# One unique entry in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query

Suppose I have (Python)

```
client = MongoClient('localhost:27017')
db = client.myFirstMB
db.countries.insert({"name": "Canada", "trump": "no"})
db.countries.insert({"name": "USA", "trump": "yes"})
```

How do I make sure **only** the Trump value must be unique? I saw something like

```
db.members.createIndex( { "user_id": 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

But that makes everything Unique, I want it so that say I have 2 `USA's` but only 1 Trump?

Comment: Do you mean for the given name trump value must be unique?

Comment: Do you mean that you only want to allow one document with `trump: "yes"`? It would be helpful if you updated your question to show the case you want to reject.